# error in matrix multiplication using pointer

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to do the matrix multiplication optimization as given [here](http://functionspace.org/articles/40):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
     }
}
```

I am trying to implement the above functionality using pointers for matrices instead of static arrays:

```
int *A,*B,*C;

   A= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(n * n));
   B= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(n * n));
   C= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(n * n));

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
      for ( k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ )
      {  sum=0;
        for ( j = 0 ;  j< n ; j++ )
        {
           double c =A[i*n + k];                              
           double d =B[k*n + j];
           sum+=c*d;                             
    }
      C[i*n + j] =sum;
      }


    }
```

But the answers are not coming same as the above code snippet.
 I am running this code in Linux ubuntu 12.04. please help resolve this issue . Is ther any logical error?

**UPDATE**

consider the following example:

```
matrix A

1  1

1  1



matrix B

1   1

1   1
```

and expected output matrix is

```
  matrix C 

  2    2 

  2    2
```

but for matrix multiplication optimization using pointers as shown above, output is different

```
   matrix C

   0    0 

   7    9
```

Comment: Show your expected output and what you are getting?

Comment: atm your allocing multiples of `int *` where it should be `int` and then trying to access an `int *` as if its a `double *`?

Comment: Think about the value of `j` after you exit the innermost loop and perform `C[i*n + j] =sum` and you should see the logic error.

Comment: taking both matrix size as A=2*2, B=2*2 and each element value in both A and B as 1, answer should come as C[0]=2,C[1]=2,C[2]=2,C[3]=2.but answer is coming different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum=0;
for ( j = 0 ;  j< n ; j++ )
{
    double c =A[i*n + k];
    double d =B[k*n + j];
    sum+=c*d;
}
C[i*n + j] =sum;
```

your code has  two problems.

1. that plus the sum is wrong. (logic error)
2. `i*n + j` when j is loop over, always n(2).

should be to

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
    for ( k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ ){
        for ( j = 0 ;  j< n ; j++ ){
            C[i*n + j] +=A[i*n + k]*B[k*n + j];//C initialized by 0
        }
    }
}
```

also should be

```
A= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n * n));//not sizeof(int*)
B= (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n * n));
C= (int*)calloc(n*n, sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

A matrix can be thought of as a 2D array, this way you can use the array addressing, which helps when reading code

I would implement dynamic array multiplying like this.

this might be a possible implementation for what you are trying to do, which is multiply 2 matrix together and store the result dynamically, I assume you have some way in which you input the matrix into the program through the command line

```
#include<stdio.h>
//this function returns a pointer to the new array. 
int **makeMatrix(int,int);

int **makeMatrix(ROWS,COLS){
int i=0;
//your code u use sizeof(*int) this is wrong suppose you use a 64bit machine 
//then sizeof(*int) is going to be 8bytes(64bits)!, whereas an integer can be 32bits, 
//the size of the integer is completely compiler dependent, does not matter if you 
//have 64bit hardware.


int **array1 = malloc(sizeof(int *)*ROWS);
for(i=0;i<Columns;i++)
array1[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*COlUMNS);
return array1;
//we are making a 2D array here so we can use array notation to address the memory
//A[row][column] is the same as *(*(A + row) + column), this makes the code neat unlike
//your method which is also very correct but i prefer the old array notation.
}

int main(void){

int set_row1,set_row2,set_row3,set_column1,set_column2,set_column3;
int row1,column1,column;

int **array1 = makeMatrix(set_row1,set_column1);
int **array2 = makeMatrix(set_row2,set_column2);
int **result = makeMatrix(set_row3,set_column3);
//now we have 3 matrices that we can use//i assume you initialise them somehow 
 //with numbers

//now the multiplication part.we can use normal array notation since we are 
// using   essentialy a 2D array, your method is also corret where you allocate the 
// entire array on a boxed piece of memory.  

//also need to check if the 2 matrix can be multiplied.
 int temp =0;
if(Column1 == Row2) //they can be multiplied together
{

for(row1=0;row1<set_row1;row1++){
   for(column2=0;column2<set_column2;column2++){
       for(column1=0;column1<set_column1;column1++){
        temp += array1[row1][column1]*array2[column1][column2]
        }
   result[row1][column2] = temp;
   }
}
else
//do something
```

!havent compiled this expect some warnings etc :)